# Loading *.rvc files from TNTmips into QGIS?

Tags: qgis, format, tntmips

I have many files obtained for a class I took in 2004. We used TNTmips to work with these files.

The file extensions are ".rvc". They show up as executable files in Mac Finder. I remember seeing somewhere that the TNTmips software used the ".rvc" file format for vector data, raster data, and -- something else.

It has been so long that I do not remember what our class used these files for, or how we used them.

Can files with the ".rvc" extension be loaded into QGIS? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also used TNT Mips and the dreaded RVC format in my faculty. 
The RVC is a container object, similar to ESRI's geodatabase format, and as far as I know it is a thoroughly closed format. I think to only way to open it is to get yourself a copy of TNT Mips and export the data from RVC to something more interoperable.